# The relationship between SAS software and SID

Tags: sas

I am very new to SAS, but found it's really a amazing tool.

Now i have a very basic and fundamental question/problem about the readiness & installation of SAS.

My boss is considering the possibility to have an environment for running PHP script directly to trigger SAS with the connection to mysql, so, i suppose we need SAS with at least "SAS Access interface for mysql" & "SAS/Intrnet", am i right?

Besides contact SAS office for help, I want to get more understandings of it first.

(A) all SAS copy contains all of these modules, and even the current SID doesnt cover "mysql & intrnet", i still can activate them after attaining another SID which has these two modules? or

(B) some SAS copies contain these modules but some are not, so, even if i had a SID which cover these two modules, it doesnt mean i can activate them for use if the installation copy do not have them actually.

It's a fundamental concept which makes me puzzle and curious, and i dont know how to explain to my boss yet....

Your kind help and information is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both are possible.  If your deployment package includes those products, then you might have them installed, even if they are not available per your license (SID file).  That depends on what was selected at installation, and when the original deployment package was created.  You (or whomever manages installations) could look at the deployment package in SAS Deployment Manager to find out.

To answer the question I think you're asking, you could certainly have one deployment package that includes the modules, and use the appropriate SID file to only activate the desired products on the desired machine(s) while still using the same deployment package.  You could also install with a SID file that does not contain them and then run a new SID that does contain them later, so long as your deployment package contains them.